# Print out order of custom post type in a loop (ex: 1 of 20)

Tags: wordpress, loops, while-loop, custom-post-type

I have a CPT called "review"

The front page displays ALL post types called "review"
I want to display the original number (order) of the post as in

1 of 20 (assume there are 20 items in the loop)
2 of 20
3 of 20

How can I get the number 1, 2, 3, etc. for each review? I was able to get the total number of items in the loop but can't get the individual.

Thanks in advance.

LOOP

```
        <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'review', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) ); ?>

        <div class="review-slider">

        <?php
        /* Start the Loop */
        while ( $loop -> have_posts() ) : $loop -> the_post(); ?>

        <?php

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/slide-review', get_post_format() );

        endwhile;

        the_posts_navigation();

    else :

        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

    endif; ?>
```

SLIDE-REVIEW

```
 <div class="slide">
   <?php the_title(); ?>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you post the php code of the loop?

Comment: Just posted it. Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THE LOOP

```
    <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'review', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) ); ?>

    <div class="review-slider">

    <?php
    /* Start the Loop */
    while ( $loop -> have_posts() ) : $loop -> the_post(); ?>

    <?php

        get_template_part( 'template-parts/slide-review', get_post_format() );

    endwhile;

    the_posts_navigation();

else :

    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

endif; ?>
```

SLIDE REVIEW

```
 <div class="slide">
   <?php the_title(); ?>
 </div>
 <div class="numberof"><?php echo $loop->current_post . ' of ' . $loop->post_count; ?></div>
```

This gets all the data from the wp query object. Does this help?

Comment: This isn't printing anything.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized i wrote `$loop->$current_post` instead of `$loop->current_post`, same goes for post_count. Any difference if you update it like this? Also forgot the `;` at the end.

Comment: I put this inside slide-review.php but it wont print anything on there. Should this be working inside the loop?

Comment: $my_post_count = $wp_query->post_count;
$index_count = $wp_query->current_post;

This did it